# ES6 unit testing - importing and exporting modules

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, karma-jasmine, babeljs

I have just worked out setting up an ES6 testing system, largely following [this tutorial](http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/writing-jasmine-unit-tests-in-es6) using the following dependencies in package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^5.8.24",
    "babel-loader": "^5.3.2",
    "jasmine": "^2.3.2",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.3.4",
    "karma": "^0.13.9",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.6",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter-livereload": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.2.1",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.7.0",
    "phantomjs": "^1.9.18",
    "webpack": "^1.12.1"
}
```

Now, to run my tests in ES6, I need to `export` the class from the client file, eg:

```
export class Calculator{

    add(op1,op2){
        return op1 + op2;
    }
    subtract(op1,op2){
        return op1 - op2;
    }
}
```

And then I need to `import` it in the testing file:

```
import {Calculator} from './es6-testing';
describe('Calculator', () => {
   it('should add two numbers', () => {
       let calculator = new Calculator();
       let sum = calculator.add(1,4);
       expect(sum).toBe(5);
   });
    it('should subtract two numbers', () => {
        let calculator = new Calculator();
        let sum = calculator.subtract(4,1);
        expect(sum).toBe(3);
    });
});
```

I am having trouble understanding why importing and exporting, in general, in this case, is required. Is there a way to get around this, for example automatically importing and exporting modules without specifying them? Having to use import and export for everything seems to be something that would get in the way of workflow very easily. What am I missing?

Comment: Do you or do you not want to use modules? Sounds like you'd rather just globals, otherwise, how do you specify what modules to use?

Comment: @Juan Mendes I would like to use globals, without having to import or export, but I couldn't figure out how to link between my testing file and my client file.

Comment: I would strongly suggest using modules over globals. Modules should not get in the way of your workflow - they should be a *part* of your workflow. The other option would be to concat the files (and optionally minify) without using modules, but that just feels like a bad idea to me.

Comment: @dvlsg @Juan Mendes so is this standard practise for testing in ES6? From now on, everything should be in a `class`?

Comment: Not necessarily. You can import/export more than just classes. For example, `export default function() { /* ... */ }` is perfectly valid syntax, and in another file you can `import someFunc from './file_with_export.js'`. You can do the same with any variables. If you have something you want to unit test, I would export it so it can be imported into not only your test suite, but also your main code library.

Comment: Here's some further reading (link taken from MDN's page for `import`): http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html -- there's a nice overview at the top detailing what you can do with ES6 modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ES6 Modules allow you to keep you code isolated. By not placing the class `Calculator` in the global scope you can reference a different class called `Calculator` elsewhere. There isn't a great way to automatically import the class if you are using modules because you need to defined which file you are referring to.